# Read raw audio file from txt in python

Tags: python

I have a binary file that contains raw audio information from stored from kinect. I want to read that file using python and then by using librosa tool to extract features. How can I read properly the file that is store in temp.txt file? The file was created using C# with the following code:

```
  void FillMemory(byte[] SoundData)
    {
        //mutex.WaitOne();
        using (MemoryMappedViewStream stream = mmfSoundData.CreateViewStream())
        {
            //set buffer to the apropriate size

            byte[] data = new byte[ByteTotransfer];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(SoundData, 0, data, 0, ByteTotransfer);
            BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(stream);
            writer.Write(data);
        }
        //mutex.ReleaseMutex();
    }
```

How can I read that file and also extract the sample rate? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read a binary file in python:

```
with open("/path/to/file.bin", "rb") as f:
    content = f.read()
    # [..] do something with content
```